# Issue with If Statements in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a program installer in batch. It will install other batch files either on to a removable media or the local hard drive. I am trying to make an IF statement to let the user decide where to install it. The first step is whether to use a hard drive or external memory. When I select hard drive it works fine but when I select external memory it runs both the hard drive code and external memory code. Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF

color 0a
TITLE Installer

ECHO Where would you like to install this?

ECHO.1) Hard Drive

ECHO.2) Removable Media

CHOICE /C:12 /N

IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 (

    ECHO Hard Drive

)
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 (

    ECHO Removable Media

)

PAUSE
```

Comment: Please leave the code formatting.

Comment: This is very confusing. As originally posted, the second `if` and the first are on the same line. SiKing's reformatting is simply applying the accepted format - and appers to render the post precisely as originally made. Please clarify why you are reverting (I reverted the code because the reformatting appered to change the code to make a partial correction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1
```

`ERRORLEVEL` will *never* be equal to `1`

you need

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1
```

or

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1
```

(where the latter means "if errorlevel is 1 or greater than 1)

Comment: Thank you. IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 worked for my purposes. I guess I just watched a bad tutorial. IF ERRORLEVEL 1 did not work I am guessing it is because greater than or equal so it would activate the other if statement.

Comment: `IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1` should not be used as it may not be available. Volatile variables aren't reliable as any other program or install program or user can kill it. Either do decending or this syntax `if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2` which only matches 1.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/if.mspx?mfr=true) (emphasis mine):

> errorlevel number : Specifies a true condition only if the previous
>   program run by Cmd.exe returned an exit code **equal to or greater
>   than number**.